# How to find the expected file transfer duration in Python?

Tags: python

I am using rsync to transfer files using `rsync` in Python. I have the basic UI where user can selects the file and initiate the transfer. I want to show the Expected Time Duration to transfer all the files they selected. I know the total size of all the files in bytes. What's the smart way to show them the expected file transfer duration? It doesn't have to be exact precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate an estimated time to completion for anything, you simply need to keep track of the amount of time taken to transfer the data currently completed and base your estimate for the rest of the data on the past speed. Once you get that basic method, there are all sorts of ways you can adjust your estimate to take account of acceleration, congestion and other effects - for example, taking the amount of data transferred in the last 100 seconds, breaking this down into 20s increments and calculating a weighted mean speed.

I'm not familiar with using rsync in Python. Are you just calling it using `os.exec*()` or are you using something like pysync (http://freecode.com/projects/pysync)? If you are spawning rsync processes, you'll struggle to get granular data (esp. if transferring large files). I suppose you could spawn `rsync --progress` and get/parse the progress lines in some sneaky way but that seems horridly awkward.

Comment: I am calling rsync with subprocess.Popen!

Comment: I'm guessing that the only metric for transfer speed is the length of time it takes for an rsync process to finish then? There's probably not a lot you can do to improve that without being awkward (trying to get data from `rsync --progress`) or using a Python implementation of the rsync algorithms. IMO, probably not worth it.